# Communication between EC2 Instances

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I am running a few EC2 Instances.  How can I communicate between them?  I have tried pinging them from within the others using private and public ips, but get no response.  One of my instances is running from Availability Zone us-east-1a and another from us-east-1d.

I am running Windows on them.

Do I need to do anything from Management Console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to :

1. set their security groups to open desired ports so they can communicate
2. use tools like telnet / curl / ping to test the connectivity

For example if you opened port 22 for ssh, you can try from instance A:

```
telnet ec2-ip-of-B-blabla.compute.amazonaws.com 22
```

And see if it connects.

Comment: I want to build an xcopy or powershell script to copy files from one ec2 instance to another.  Wondering what port and tool I would use to do this?  Any ideas?  Thanks for the help...

Comment: Open port 22 (ssh) and use scp.

Answer (score 1):

Ping is not a reliable tool in most cloud providers - ICMP packets (which are used by ping) are often blocked.

It is better to use a tool like telnet (you can install telnet client from Add/Remove windows components - it is not there by default).

Then use the command:

```
telnet <IP or URL> <port>
```

In your case, you should use port 5985, which is the WinRM protocol port that Powershell uses for connecting to remote machines.

On EC2, the WinRM service is on by default, so you don't need to do anything on the Windows VM. You do need to open port 5985 in your security group. You should probably only open this port for access from machines in the same security group - don't open this port for public access from the internet.

You may also want to open port 445 in the security group. This is used for the CIFS protocol - Windows file sharing. So you can access files from remote machines using:

```
\\<Machine IP>\\C$
```

Same security restrictions should be set on port 445 - open it only for members in the same security group. Note that CIFS is not an encrypted protocol - use it only between machines inside the Amazon cloud.